# D3.js data() key binding

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

This is my fist time of using `D3.js` to build a bar chart inside a React application.
My component is quite simple: it gets in data and should draw a bar chart.
I want to add keys to my bars, but when I try to do that in `data()` function it fails on `=> entry.item`

> Object is of type 'unknown'.  TS2571

```
...
 svg
      .selectAll(".bar")
      .data( data, entry => entry.item )
      .join("rect")
...
```

My `data` is of this type:

```
export interface DataFormat {
  item: string;
  region: string;
  data: number;
}
```

I don't get what am I doing wrong, since type definition for `data()` shows:

```
data<NewDatum>(data: NewDatum[], key?: ValueFn<GElement | PElement, Datum | NewDatum, string>): Selection<GElement, NewDatum, PElement, PDatum>;
```

UPD:
Here is how `data` is defined

```
export interface ChartProps {
  data: DataFormat[];
}

export const Chart = (props:ChartProps) => {
  const { data } = props;
```

and in the parent component it is passed as a prop:

```
export const Wrapper = () => {
  const [currentYear, setCurrentYear] = useState<number>(INITIAL_YEAR);
  const [dataMax, setDataMax] = useState<number>(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState<DataFormat[]>(initialData);

  useEffect(() => {
    if( currentYear <= FINAL_YEAR ) {
      setTimeout(() => setCurrentYear(currentYear+1), 200);
    }
  }, [currentYear]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data: DataFormat[] = populationData.data
      .map((dataitem) => {
        return {
          item: dataitem.item,
          data: dataitem.data[currentYear],
          region: dataitem.region,
          image: dataitem.image,
        };
      })
      .sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data)
      .slice(0, TOP);
    setData(data);
    setDataMax(Math.max(...data.map((item) => item.data)));
  }, [currentYear]);

  return (
    <Chart data={data} />
  );
};
```

Comment: Please show your definition of `data`. Is it loaded via Fetch API? How is it typed to interface `DataFormat`?

Comment: @altocumulus `data` is passed as a prop from parent component.
There it is stored using `useState()`, and mutated via `useEffect()`. Initially it's a `JSON` file.

Comment: Please share the relevant code snippets for that. Not sure about passing the prop, the typing might get lost along the way. Again, nearly impossible to tell without seeing your code. Reminds me of my recent answer to [*"How to make data() key function to work with TypeScript?"*](/q/61040750).

Comment: @altocumulus Please check my update about how `data` is defined